# Firefox checkbox style issue

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am trying to correct the styling of some custom styled checkboxes I have created. They look great in all browsers apart from FireFox?
I have replicated the issues here: https://jsfiddle.net/y6Lty5nm/
If you open this up in chrome it looks great but in ***FireFox*** its almost like its ignoring the styles completely?

```css
 input[type="checkbox"]{
        appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        background-color: #999999;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 100px;
        -moz-border-radius:100px;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
        background-color: #19a89d;
    }
    
    input[type="checkbox"]:focus{
        outline: none;
    }
    
    input[type="checkbox"]:hover{
        background-color: #19a89d;
    }
```

```html
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="chck" data-filter=".sp" id="sp"><p>Super Parent</p></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="chck" data-filter=".cf" id="cf"><p>Control Freak</p></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="chck" data-filter=".fs" id="fd"><p>Food Snob</p></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="chck" data-filter=".bh" id="bh"><p>Bean Head</p></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="chck" data-filter=".bb" id="bb"><p>Busy Bee</p></li>
```

I have looked this up on Google and Stack and have of course seen others wit the same issue, I have tried applying the web kits but it seems to ignore them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [multiple](https://coderwall.com/p/a7tbrq/protip-if-you-want-to-style-checkboxes-radio-buttons-or-select-menus-in-firefox-don-t-bother) [records](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=605985) of bugs within firefox specifically for styling checkboxes and radio buttons.

My recommendation is to write your own solution.

```css
label input[type="checkbox"]{ display: none; }

label input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .cr > .cr-icon{
    transform: scale(1) rotateZ(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
}

label input[type="checkbox"] + .cr > .cr-icon{
    transform: scale(3) rotateZ(-20deg);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" checked="">
    <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>
    Click Me
</label>
```

Comment: This is the method I used in the end but by firming up this for me makes me feel at ease.